# Why preg_match("/[^(22|75)]/", "25") returns false?

Tags: php, regex

I want to test that a given string does not belong to the following group of strings: 22 75.

Could anyone please tell why PHP's **`preg_match("/[^(22|75)]/", "25")`** returns *0*?

The weirdest thing is that `preg_match("/[^(22|76)]/", "25")` returns *1* as expected...

Edit:
I guess I understand the reason and the nature of my mistake, not how to make a check that a given two-digit number does not match 20,21,22,23,24, 75,76,77,78,79,80 ? 
I need to assemble an expression to check a given age against the list of allowed ages (this presumes only two-digit numbers)

I can not use anything other than `preg_match()` (`!preg_match()` is not available in my case), I can only play with RegEx pattern.

Comment: `preg_match` does not return true, it returns either `0` when no match is found, `1` if a match is found or `false` if your regex is bad.

Comment: RainFromHeaven, you are totally right, but this is not the nature of the question.

Comment: It isn't, but your previous statements were incorrect. Precision won't hurt anyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Time for a Regular Expressions Lesson!

---

### Explanation of your regular expressions

> `[^(22|75)]`

Matches false because it is looking for the following:

- A single character NOT in this list of characters: `|()275`

> `[^(22|76)]`

Matches true because it is looking for:

- A single character NOT in this list of characters: `|()276`

### Why does it do this?

You wrapped your regex in a **[character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html)** (click for more info)

To give an example of how character classes work, look at this regex:

> `[2222222222222221111111199999999999]`

This character class will only match ONE character, if it is a `2`,`1` or a `9`.

### How to make it work for you:

To match the number 25 (or 22, 52, and 55), you can use this character class:

> `[25]{2}`

This will match a 2 digit number containing either `2` or `5` at either place.

Answer (score 3):

### What are character classes

A character class is a collection of **characters** (not strings). With a character class, you're telling the regex engine to match **only one** out of several characters.

For example, if you wanted to match an `a` or `e`, you'd write `[ae]`. If you wanted to match `grey` or `gray`, you'd write `gr[ae]y`.

### Explanation for first regex

```
[^(22|75)]
```

As said above, character classes match a **single character** from the list. Here, you're using `^` to get a negated character class, so this will match a single character that's **not** in the supplied list. In this case, our list contains the following characters:

```
( 2 2 | 7 5 )
```

Multiple characters are only counted once. So this effectively becomes:

```
( 2 | 7 5 )
```

`25`  is the string you're matching against. The regular expression asks: **Does the supplied string contains a single character that's not in the above list?** `2` and `5` are in the list, so the answer is **No**. That explains why `preg_match()` returns `false` (not `false`, `0` to be precise).

### Explanation for second regex

```
/[^(22|76)]/
```

It is same as above. The only difference here is that `5` changed to `6`. It now checks for the absense of any of the following characters:

```
( 2 | 7 6 )
```

The supplied string is still the same as before - `25`. **Does the string contain any character that's not in the list above? Yes!** It *does* contain `5` (which is not in the list anymore). That explains why `preg_match()` returns `1`.

### Difference between character classes and alternation

They look similar but they do different things. Alternation can be used when you want to match a **single regular expression** out of several possible regular expressions. Unlike character classes, alternation works with a regex. A simple string, say `foo` is also a valid regular expression. It matches `f` followed by `o`, followed by `o`.

Use character class when you want to match one of the included characters. Use alternation when you want to match between n number of strings.

### How should you modify the regex to obtain correct results

Negate your `preg_match()` call and use the regex `(22|75)`:

```
if (!preg_match('/(22|75)/', '25')) {
    # code...
}
```

This is the easiest approach. If you want to achieve this directly using a regex, then you may want to use look-arounds.

### Alternative solution

If this is exactly what you're trying to do, then you don't need a regular expression at all. Leverage PHP's built-in functions for string manipulation! Not only it will be faster, it will be more readable too.

In this case, a simple [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) should suffice:

```
if(!in_array('25', array(25,75))) {
    # code ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In regular expression, `[...]` match any character inside the bracket.

To be more correct:

- `[^...]`: match any charcter not listed inside the bracket. (`^`: negate)

Remove the `[`, and `]` if you want to match string that starts with `22` or `76`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is asking "does the string contain a character that is not `(`, `2`, `7`, `5`, `|` or `)`?"

This is obviously not what you want.

Try this:

```
if( !in_array("25", array("22","75")))
```

Answer (score 0):

^ inside of [...] is a negation of a character list.
(22|76)

Regex multiple character negation is a very tricky subject and can't be easily resolved.

But you could invert the return result of preg_match function ie.:

```
if(!preg_match('@22|76@', '25', $matches))
    doSomething();
```